# MERN - update specific string in an array's object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am using mongoose to connect my backend (Express) server to database. I want to do normal `CRUD` operations - but I am able to do it only for direct data in object, but I need to be able to access also array data.

Example of my model:

```
const LeewaySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    shirt: [
        {
            name: String,
            image: String,
        },
    ],
```

With the following code I am able to update only **name** of the object, but I need to be able to update also **name** in **shirt array**

Here is working approach when changing name of object:

```
app.put('/update', async (req, res) => {
    const updateName = req.body.updateName;
    const id = req.body.id;
    console.log(updateName, id);
    try {
        await ClosetModel.findById(id, (error, closetToUpdate) => {
            closetToUpdate.name = updateName;
            closetToUpdate.save();
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.send('success');
});
```

And I tried the same with shirt array, just specifying the correct path

```
app.put('/update-shirt', async (req, res) => {
    const updateShirtName = req.body.updateShirtName;
    const id = req.body.id;

    try {
        await ClosetModel.findById(id, (error, closetToUpdate) => {
            closetToUpdate.shirt.name = updateShirtName; // different path here
            closetToUpdate.save();
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.send('success');
});
```

The server crashes and `/update-shirt` conflicts with `/update` path

I am using the same route and frontend for READ

```
   useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:8000/read')
            .then((response) => {
                setListOfClosets(response.data);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log('error');
            });
    }, []);
```

And update name function calling with button onClick:

```
const updateCloset = (id) => {
    const updateName = prompt('Enter new data');

    axios
        .put('http://localhost:8000/update', {
            updateName: updateName,
            id: id,
        })
        .then(() => {
            setListOfClosets(
                listOfClosets.map((val) => {
                    return val._id === id
                        ? {
                              _id: id,
                              name: updateName,
                              email: val.email,
                          }
                        : val;
                })
            );
        });
};
```

I don't really know how to do update for **shirt's name**, I tried to copy paste and just change path and url of course, but it did not work.

Comment: I think you need to know how to update a sub-document field value (`name`) within an array field (`shirt`). Maybe you can try such update in `mongosh` and see how it works (and then apply in your web app).

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't actually describe what specific transformation (update) you are attempting to apply to the document. Without knowing *what* you are attempting to do, there is no way for us to help advise on *how* to do it.

Say, for example, that the document of interest looks like this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  shirt: [
    {  name: "first shirt", image: "path to first shirt" },
    {  name: "second shirt", image: "path to second shirt" },
    {  name: "third shirt", image: "path to third shirt" }     
  ]
}
```

Also let's say that the application hits the `/update-shirt` endpoint with an `id` of `1` and a `updateShirtName` of `"updated shirt name"`. Which entry in the array is that string supposed to be applied to? Similarly, how would that information be passed to the server for it to construct the appropriate update.

It is absolutely possible to update documents in an array, [here is some documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) about that specifically. But the actual structure of the command depends on the logic that you are attempting to provide from the application itself.

The only other thing that comes to mind here is that the motivation for the schema described in the question seems a little unclear. Why is the `shirt` field defined as an array here? Perhaps it should instead just be an embedded document. If so then the mechanics of updating the field in the subdocument are more straightforward and none of the aforementioned concerns about updating arrays remain relevant.

Answer (score -1):

just make an update api where you just have to pass the id and and pass the shirt in the findByIdAndUpdate query and hit the postman by passing the below code.

```
shirt: [
        {
            name: "jhrh",
            image: String,
        },
    ],
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this helps answer the original question related to updating values in an array? What is an 'update api' and how does it resolve a problem with updating arrays versus other fields in the document?

Comment: the user wants to update name field in shirt array, so he can update this just simply by passing above values to postman. My reference to update api is basically make an update function( where update query will be written ) and give route to that function i.e, what i am calling 'update api' and pass the above parameters, i did the same thing and it worked fine.

Comment: _Which_ entry in the array though? It the array only ever has one entry then it shouldn't be an array (and should just be an embedded document instead)

Comment: i am just giving an example, it can have multiple enteries. I am too lazy to add multiple enteries in the array so i just took one.